# Get sublists' name within parent list

Tags: r, dataframe, list, extract, nested-lists

I have the following list:

```
Item1 <- data.frame(Col1 = rnorm(10000), Col2 = rnorm(10000), Col3 = rnorm(10000), Col4 = rnorm(10000))
Item2 <- data.frame(Col1 = rnorm(10000), Col2 = rnorm(10000), Col3 = rnorm(10000), Col4 = rnorm(10000))
Item3 <- data.frame(Col1 = rnorm(10000), Col2 = rnorm(10000), Col3 = rnorm(10000), Col4 = rnorm(10000))
Item4 <- data.frame(Col1 = rnorm(10000), Col2 = rnorm(10000), Col3 = rnorm(10000), Col4 = rnorm(10000))
Item5 <- data.frame(Col1 = rnorm(10000), Col2 = rnorm(10000), Col3 = rnorm(10000), Col4 = rnorm(10000))

dflist <- list(Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5)
```

and a following vector:

```
vec <- c("Item3", "Item4")
```

Each item inside that list is a data.frame, that contains 10K observations stored in 4 columns.

What I would like to do first, is for each data.frame inside `dflist` to check if its name (within `dflist`) is present inside `vec`. Next, if so, then apply row-wise logic: everything after first negative value shall be set to 0. My idea is to use a combination of do.call/lapply/apply. I cannot use loops, execution time is a priority here.

Now, with the second part of the task (writing a function to be applied row-wise within each `dflist` element) I will manage. The only struggle I have, is how to extract the name of a data.frame when "lapplying" a function checking if each item is inside `vec`.

A pseudo-code that I had in mind would look like the following:

```
CheckPresence <- function(dataframe){
... (?) ...
}
```

```
Adjust <- function(row){
...
}
```

```
MakeAdjustments <- function(dflist, vec){

if(CheckPresence(dataframe) %in% vec){ #e.g. Item1, Item2 etc.
dataframe_adjusted <- apply(X=dataframe, MARGIN=1, FUN=Adjust)
}else{
dataframe_adjusted <- dataframe
}
}
```

and then

```
adjustedlist <- lapply(X=dflist, FUN= MakeAdjustments, vec)
```

Comment: The problem is, that your data.frames don't have their names any more in your `dflist`. Use: `dflist <- mget(c("Item1", "Item2"))` or `dflist <- list(Item1=Item1, Item2=Item2)` .

Comment: You can also use `tibble::lst` (which stores the symbol as the name), as `lst(Item1, Item2, ...)`. (Really only useful if you're already using `dplyr` or other packages in the `tidyverse`.)

Comment: `setNames` might also be useful. In your case: `dflist <- setNames(dflist, paste0('Item', 1:5))` or similar

Comment: Ok, but how does naming list elements is beneficial to me in this case? How do I retrieve it within `CheckPresence` ? I also would like to retain the structure of `dflist`